# Visual Studio Upgrade Error

Tags: visual-studio

I've upgraded Visual Studio from 2010 to 2015 but i'm getting a project incompatible error as per the screenshot below:

[image]

When i open the ****.csproj_deploy.wdproj file here's the contents, company name redacted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
  Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Project 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=104956

-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectName>*********</ProjectName>
    <BuildDir>..\..\..\..\target</BuildDir>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>10.0.30319</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{4981E0AB-A55B-46AE-B55F-B607E3B4EAA5}</ProjectGuid>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\..\webapp</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebProject>{BF29C57D-D568-4195-9DE5-E5F179E19A0C}|src\main\webapp\*********.csproj</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/*********.csproj</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>*********.csproj_deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
    <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>false</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <DeleteAppDataFolder>false</DeleteAppDataFolder>
    <VirtualDirectoryAlias>
    </VirtualDirectoryAlias>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>*********.csproj_deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'goss-test|AnyCPU' ">
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <SingleAssemblyName>*********.csproj_deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <DeployPath>E:\dotnet-sites\eastrenintranet</DeployPath>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '*********-intranet-dev|AnyCPU' ">
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <SingleAssemblyName>*********.csproj_deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '*********-intranet-live|AnyCPU' ">
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <SingleAssemblyName>*********.csproj_deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\.svn\**\*" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\bin\*.xml" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\lucene\**\*" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\media\**\*" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\obj\**\*" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\*.csproj" />
    <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*.user" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\webapp\*********.csproj">
      <Project>{BF29C57D-D568-4195-9DE5-E5F179E19A0C}</Project>
      <Name>*********</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
        <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\cache\**\*" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\webapp\*********.csproj">
            <Project>{BF29C57D-D568-4195-9DE5-E5F179E19A0C}</Project>
            <Name>eastren-intranet</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <IncludeInBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\**\*" Exclude="@(ExcludeFromBuild)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
    <Target Name="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" BeforeTargets="Rebuild">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(IncludeInBuild)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildDir)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="BeforeMerge">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterMerge">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Rebuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - BEGIN" />
        <!-- Copy in any configuration files overwriting any previous ones -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <ConfigFiles Include="..\..\config\$(Configuration)\**\*.*" Exclude="..\..\config\$(Configuration)\**\.svn\**" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - Copying configuration files" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ConfigFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)" />
        <!-- Create a ZIP archive of the entire built site -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <ZipFiles Include="$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildDir)" Condition="!Exists('$(BuildDir)')" />
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - Zipping work directory $(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)\ " />
        <Zip Files="@(ZipFiles)" WorkingDirectory="$(BuildDir)\$(Configuration)\" ZipFileName="$(BuildDir)\$(ProjectName)-$(Configuration)$(Version).zip" ZipLevel="9" />
        <!-- Auto deploy new site if on test -->
        <ItemGroup Condition="$(DeployPath) != ''">
            <SiteFiles Include="$(DeployPath)\**\*.*" Exclude="$(DeployPath)\.htaccess" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - Removing deployment directory $(DeployPath) " />
        <Delete Condition="$(DeployPath) != ''" Files="@(SiteFiles)" />
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - Unzipping site file $(DeployPath) " />
        <Unzip Condition="$(DeployPath) != ''" ZipFileName="$(BuildDir)\$(ProjectName)-$(Configuration)$(Version).zip" TargetDirectory="$(DeployPath)" />
        <Message Text="*** Target: Rebuild - END " />
    </Target>
 </Project>
```

How do i resolve this issue?

I can build the solution ok without any errors and the site displays ok on localhost.  MSBUILD also runs ok and on the face of it, i can't see an issue with the output.

Please advise

thanks

Comment: Do you have a Setup Project as part of the solution?

Comment: No i don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013/2015 don't support Setup and deployment -projects out of the box. Install extension to enable those:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

Comment: Hi, i've installed that and restarted Visual Studio but the proj still says incompatible. The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=659044&projecttype=2CFEAB61-6A3B-4EB8-B523-560B4BEEF521